# Why is typescript giving me an error in my IDE saying that properties that are on an Observable do not exist but showing that they do?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently trying to create an auto authenticate method in my authorization service file for my Angular SPA. When I used the method three months ago, these things were not an issue.  Now for some reason I am getting these typescript errors in my IDE and I would like to understand what I am doing wrong and what I need to do to fix them.  Below is my method that I am trying to use followed by images of the errors and an interface I wrote thinking that maybe was the problem.  Any assistance would greatly be appreciated.

```
autoAuthenticateUser() {
const AuthInformation = this.getAuthData();
if (!AuthInformation) {
  return;
}
const now = new Date();
const expiresIn = AuthInformation.expirationDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
//console.log(AuthInformation, expiresIn);
if (expiresIn > 0) {
  this.token = AuthInformation.token;
  this.isAuthenticated = true;
  this.userId = AuthInformation.userId;
  this.isAdmin = AuthInformation.isAdmin;
  this.setAuthTimer(expiresIn / 1000);
  this.authStatusListener.next(true);
}
```

}

[image: Interface]

[image: Method with errors]

[image: Error message in IDE.]

Also here is the other method associated with the first which is my getAuthData method.

```
private getAuthData() {
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
const expirationDate = localStorage.getItem('expiration');
const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
const isAdmin = localStorage.getItem('isAdmin');
if (!token || !expirationDate) {
  return of(null);
}
return {
  token: token,
  expirationDate: new Date(expirationDate),
  userId: userId,
  isAdmin: isAdmin
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us `getAuthData`?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have included that as well.  I have edited the original question to include the getAuthData method as well.

Comment: you have few issues with your naming conventions, first your const AuthImformation uses the same name as your Interface, and also starts with UpperCase (which not related to this issue but good to know)

Comment: I will fix the unrelated issue, thank you.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code as text, not as pictures of text.

Comment: I apologize, I did not realize it mattered as long as all the relevant code was represented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `getAuthData` can return `of(null)`. Notice that the error says `Property 'expirationDate' does not exist on type Observable<any> | { expirationDate: Date ... }`. This is a union type.

The `getAuthData` has two `return` branches, so TypeScript interprets this as returning the union of these two types.

It depends a bit on how you want your app to work, but it seems like you should just return `null` instead of `of(null)`. If you do, you may get another error that the `AuthInformation` is possibly null. In that case, you can either update your app so that `getAuthData` can only return valid auth in the first place, or you do an additional conditional check to see that `AuthInformation` is properly populated.